# Optimizing Node MySQL Query for CPU Utilization

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am working on a NodeJS port listener code that listens to a particular TCP port on the server. The obtaining the data from the port, the data is split using a delimited (for instance comma `,`) and inserts this data into the MySQL database.

I have written the code and I was successfully able to insert data into MySQL server. My issue is that the process is consuming more CPU than expected.

For instance, I ran the code on a 2 core 4 GB RAM Linux Server. The process consumes about 25-50% CPU when only one packet is received every 60 secs. The project should be able to listen to at least 00 packets of data per second on this configuration.

```
var net = require('net');

    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var PORT = 5000;

    net.createServer(function(sock) {
     console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);

  sock.on('data', function(data) {

    console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
    var dataArray = data.toString().split(',');

    var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: hostname,
    user: "abc",
    password: "123",
    database: "abc",
    connectionLimit:100
});

  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "INSERT INTO `table`(`val1`, `val2`, `val3`, `val4`, `val5`, `val6`) VALUES ('1','"+dataArray[6]+"','"+dataArray[10]+"','"+dataArray[9]+"','"+dataArray[11]+"','"+dataArray[13]+"')";
  console.log(sql);

  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) throw err;

  connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    connection.release() 
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log("Data Inserted into Table1");
  });

  var sql = "INSERT INTO `table2`(`datafield`) VALUES ('"+data+"')";
  console.log(sql);
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) throw err;

  connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    connection.release() 
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Data Inserted into Table2");
  });

    sock.write('You said "' + data + '"');

    connection.release();
  });

 sock.on('close', function(data) {

   console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);

 });
}).listen(PORT);

console.log('Server listening on '+ PORT);
```

Comment: Please take care to format your code correctly.

Comment: I have removed the ` from the code, which I think was the issue with the format.

Comment: Also do you need all those bloating empty lines?

Comment: Not Necessarily. It can be removed, not an issue. But do you have a solution to the issue I face? How can we optimized the solution for lesser CPU consumption?

Comment: Your code is not complete both `net.createServer` and `sock.on` do not close! I've attempted to correct this and other minor formatting issues so that everyone can read your intent... have ya by chance looked into `async` and `await`? ... I've a feeling that such _syntactic sugar_ might be a _treat_ for making the code a bit more responsive.

Comment: Thank you S0AndS0. Yes that was a mistake. I had opened connections each time data was listened to. I have fixed the code.

Comment: But that doesn't solve my issue completely. I am not able to get maximized CPU utilization. With only 1 packet being send every 30 seconds, my CPU utilization shouldn't be more than 1 percent.

Comment: _sock.on('data'_ and _net.createServer_ are not closed.